# why django user password doesnt encrypted while i create new user?

Tags: python, django, model

im trying to make my own custom user model with `AbstractUser` class

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

but when i create new account the password field wont been encrypted it show only a plain text !
i think i should use `BaseUserManager` but i dont have any idea to make it 
thanks , regards ..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow @art_cs. Can you please show me how are you creating the new user?

Comment: from admin url , i will update the post with the capture of the screen

Comment: Did you also change the admin for `CustomUser`? if yes please share the code for that as well.

Comment: no , just this line (admin,site.register) its all

Comment: your custom user admin must also be inherited from the `UserAdmin` of Django. check my answer.

Comment: thanks alot , i fixed using UserAdmin

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't exactly know how are you creating the new user, my guess is you are doing something like,

```
user = CustomUser.objects.create(username="boohoo", email="boo@hoo.com", password="boohoopass")
```

This user object will store the password as plain text. Django doesn't automatically converts the text to hashed value instead if you dig deeper you'll find a method called `make_password` or there's a method in `AbstractUser`, `set_password` which basically converts the string to hash value. So when you create a user, use either of these methods.

```
user = CustomUser.objects.create(username="boohoo", email="boo@hoo.com")

user.passowrd = make_password("boohoopass")

# or 

user.set_password("boohoopass")
```

Even better approach is to use the method in the `UserManager`, `create_user`, which automatically does this for you.

```
user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username="boohoo", email="boo@hoo.com", password="boohoopass")
```

**UPDATED**
In your case your admin class must also inherit from `UserAdmin` from django. Because User admin also calls the specific functions to make such things like password hash keys.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as OrigUserAdmin


@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(OrigUserAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'is_active'
    )
```

Comment: i will try to make UserManager class , i dont have any idea ,how to make in my case ! i only add two extra fields , that why i dont know how to manage them in UserManager class , thanks for helping

Comment: That's already there, it's part of `AbstractUser` class. check line 326 (hopefully) of `AbstractUser` class, where it defines `objects = UserManager()`

Comment: i also add objects  = UserManager() to CustomUser but still wont encrypted !

Comment: @art_cs you didn't have to do that as manager is already part of `AbstractUser` check UPDATED part of my answer. I think your problem lies in the Admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a save method for encrypting the password for the custom user model.
Use the below code for the AbstractUser method for creating encrypted password:

```
class CustomModel(AbstractUser):
    .......
    
    def save(self):
        user = super(CustomModel, self)
        user.set_password(self.password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to crypto the password yourself.

An easy way to do that is make a use a library like cryptography 
you can install it with `pip install cryptography`

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
tasty_salt = b'some tasty salt to help us digest that password'
def hashPassword(password):
  digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend())
  digest.update(str.encode(password))
  digest.update(tasty_salt)
  return digest.finalize()


def verifyPassword(input_password,hashed_password):#get hashed_password from your user model
  digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256(), backend=default_backend())
  digest.update(str.encode(input_password))
  digest.update(tasty_salt)
  return digest.finalize() == hashed_password

print(verifyPassword('password',hashPassword('password')))
```

this will let you hash password in your user model. Just import it into your project and you should be good to go.